# about Rieman-integrable functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration

let $f: [ \mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be Rieman-integrable and $\int_{a}^{b} f^{2}(x) d x=0$ and let $Z(f)=\{x \in [ \mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}] |f(x)=0\}$ and $D$ be set of continous points of $f$ now which of following options is true ?

1- $Z(f) \subseteq D$

2-$D \subseteq Z(f)$

3-$D$ is countable set

4-$Z(f)$ is countable set

I think if we set $f(x)=0$ then 3 and 4 are false .

Comment: 2. is true.  1. probably true f=0 almost everywhere.  I suspect that being Riemann integrable, it is continuous almost everywhere, leaving non-zero points as isolated points.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)$ is continuous at point $x_0$ and $f(x)>0$, then there exists a neighborhood $(a_1,b_1)$ of $x_0$ such that $(f(x))^2 > \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon$ strictly above zero. Since $(f(x))^2$ is non-negative, $\int_a^b (f(x))^2 \mathrm d x \ge \int_{a_1}^{b_1} (f(x))^2 \mathrm d x > 0$, which is not possible. So $x_0\in D$ implies $x_0 \in Z(f)$.

For (1), set $[a,b]$ to be $[-1,1]$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x=\frac 1n$ where $n$ is an integer, and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. Then $(f(x))^2=f(x)$ is Riemann-integrable, for its points of discontinuity has Lebesgue measure zero, and the integral equals $0$. But $f$ is not continuous at point zero.